For...Each Loop Exiting After Finding First Match
I have an Excel (VBA) test sub that first searches for named ranges that have the word "Date" in them. Then it's supposed to search through the found named range for all cells in column (2) that have the word "Sunday" in the Cell.Text. However, after finding the first match, and performing the required function, it exits the loop without searching for anymore occurrences.
I have tried using both looking for a match ("Sunday"), using the cell's text, and searching for a match using the cell's value of "vbSunday". Both attempts end the same way, exiting the loop after finding the first match.
Here is my code:
Public Sub Test1()
    Dim NR As Name
    Dim CellCount As Integer
    Dim Cell As Range
    CellCount = 0
    For Each NR In ThisWorkbook.Names 'Look at each named range within the workbook.
        If InStr(NR.Name, "Date") <> 0 Then 'Check the named range name contains specific text.
            For Each Cell In NR.RefersToRange.Columns(2).Cells
                If InStr(Cell.Text, "Sunday") = 1 Then
                    CellCount = CellCount + 1
                    MsgBox (CellCount)
                    Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Else
                    Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What language is this?  You will probably get better answers if you add a tag for the specific language.

This question is similar to: Breaking/exit nested for in vb.net. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Add a line Debug.Print NR.Name, Range(NR).Address(1, 1, , 1) after For Each NR In ThisWorkbook.Names and a line Debug.Print Cell.Address, Cell.Value after For Each Cell In NR.RefersToRange.Columns(2).Cells. Check immediate window for results.

i've not seen 'Next [object]' at the bottom of a next loop in VBS, just 'Next'. maybe 'Next NR' and 'Next Cell' should just be 'Next'.
cant say without seeing your data, really.
InStr([text], [search], 1) is case insensitive, btw, should that be part of your issue.

This seems to be a comment, and not an actual answer to the question. If so, it should be deleted. Commenting on other people's posts is a privilege gained from earning reputation - if you haven't earned it yet, try to get comfortable writing answers first.

Hide Rows Containing a Specific Day of the Week (Date)

Assuming the critical cells contain dates.

Sub HideSundays()
    
    Const CRITERIA_COLUMN As Long = 2
    Const WEEK_DAY As Long = vbSunday
    Const NAME_CONTAINS As String = "Date"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' If it isn't, reference it by using its name or use 'ActiveWorkbook'.
    
    Dim nm As Name, rg As Range, crg As Range, cell As Range, Value As Variant
    Dim CellsCount As Long
    
    For Each nm In wb.Names
        If InStr(1, nm.Name, NAME_CONTAINS, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ' A=a
            Set rg = Nothing
            Set crg = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
                Set rg = nm.RefersToRange
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rg Is Nothing Then ' the name is a range
                If rg.Columns.Count >= CRITERIA_COLUMN Then
                    Set crg = rg.Columns(CRITERIA_COLUMN)
                End If
            'Else ' the name is not a range
            End If
            If Not crg Is Nothing Then ' the range has enough columns
                crg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                For Each cell In crg.Cells
                    Value = cell.Value
                    If IsDate(Value) Then ' the cell is a date
                        If Weekday(Value) = WEEK_DAY Then ' cell is a 'Sunday'
                            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                            CellsCount = CellsCount + 1
                        'Else ' the cell is no 'Sunday'
                        End If
                    'Else ' the cell is no date
                    End If
                Next cell
            'Else ' the range hasn't got enough columns
            End If
        'Else ' the name doesn't contain 'Date'
        End If
    Next nm

    MsgBox CellsCount & " row" & IIf(CellsCount = 1, "", "s") & " hidden.", _
        IIf(CellsCount = 0, vbExclamation, vbInformation)

End Sub

